# loop logic can't effect every element

Tags: php, loops, logic

thanks in advance for helping, and looking.

I have a bunch of images whose paths and metadata I need to process in a web directory:
e.g. 'path/to/files/u_1.jpg'

```
$list=array_values($list);
foreach ($list as &$value)
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($dir.$udir.$value);
   $value = $predir.$udir.$value.$wid.$width.$hgt.$height.$lft.$end;
```

I used scandir to get the elements into the $list array correctly.
The rest of variables, are basically creating the img tags in an html page.

However, what I get is only the last element done correctly, the rest do not come out of the loop:

```
Array
(
[0] => u_1.jpg
...
[16] => u_8.jpg
[17] => img src="/images/photo/up/u_9.jpg" style="display: none; width: 1526px; height: 1080px; left: 0px; top: px; ">
)
```

But the metadata is correctly found (image height and width for that image).

What I need is to get every line to look like the last.  I have searched but I think this may be a fundamental logic issue.  Is there a way to pass the info to another holding array, or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `{}` `foreach` will consider on the next line to it. So only for the last element the values are set. Put `{}`s so that the `foreach` know what to process. Try with -

```
foreach ($list as &$value) {
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($dir.$udir.$value);
   $value = $predir.$udir.$value.$wid.$width.$hgt.$height.$lft.$end;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was supremely embarrassing.  I did look it up.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

You need brackets around the body of your foreach loop:

```
foreach ($list as &$value) {
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($dir.$udir.$value);
   $value = $predir.$udir.$value.$wid.$width.$hgt.$height.$lft.$end;
}
```

If you leave out the brackets, only the very next line after the foreach declaration gets executed by the loop. In your example, without brackets, the second line is only called once, after the loop is already finished.

Comment: Thanks for your time looking at this, I appreciate it.